# Why MySQL optimizer doesn't use all columns index?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization, percona

Percona MySQL 5.7

table scheeme:

```
CREATE TABLE Developer.Rate (
  ID bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  TIME datetime NOT NULL,
  BASE varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  QUOTE varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  BID double NOT NULL,
  ASK double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  INDEX IDX_TIME (TIME),
  UNIQUE INDEX IDX_UK (BASE, QUOTE, TIME)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
ROW_FORMAT = COMPRESSED;
```

I try to make request for latests data before selected period. The optimazer use no-complete unique key, only 2 columns of 3.

If I do request in common way:

```
EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON
SELECT
  BID
FROM 
  Rate
WHERE 
  BASE = 'EUR' 
  AND QUOTE = 'USD' 
  AND `TIME` <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
ORDER BY 
  `TIME` DESC 
LIMIT 1
;
```

"Explain" shows that only 2 first columns of index are used: BASE, QUOTE

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "10231052.40"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": false,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "Rate",
        "access_type": "ref",
        "possible_keys": [
          "IDX_UK",
          "IDX_TIME"
        ],
        "key": "IDX_UK",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "BASE",
          "QUOTE"
        ],
        "key_length": "22",
        "ref": [
          "const",
          "const"
        ],
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 45966462,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 22983231,
        "filtered": "50.00",
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "1037760.00",
          "eval_cost": "4596646.20",
          "prefix_cost": "10231052.40",
          "data_read_per_join": "1G"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "ID",
          "TIME",
          "BASE",
          "QUOTE",
          "BID"
        ],
        "attached_condition": "((`Developer`.`Rate`.`BASE` <=> 'EUR') and (`Developer`.`Rate`.`QUOTE` <=> 'USD') and (`Developer`.`Rate`.`TIME` <= <cache>((now() - interval 1 month))))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But if you force the optimizer to use IDX_UK, MySQL uses all 3 columns in the request:

```
EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON
SELECT
  BID
FROM 
  Rate FORCE INDEX(IDX_UK)
WHERE 
  BASE = 'EUR' 
  AND QUOTE = 'USD' 
  AND `TIME` <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
ORDER BY 
  `TIME` DESC 
LIMIT 1

{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "10231052.40"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": false,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "Rate",
        "access_type": "range",
        "possible_keys": [
          "IDX_UK"
        ],
        "key": "IDX_UK",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "BASE",
          "QUOTE",
          "TIME"
        ],
        "key_length": "27",
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 45966462,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 15320621,
        "filtered": "100.00",
        "index_condition": "((`Developer`.`Rate`.`BASE` = 'EUR') and (`Developer`.`Rate`.`QUOTE` = 'USD') and (`Developer`.`Rate`.`TIME` <= <cache>((now() - interval 1 month))))",
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "1037760.00",
          "eval_cost": "3064124.31",
          "prefix_cost": "10231052.40",
          "data_read_per_join": "818M"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "ID",
          "TIME",
          "BASE",
          "QUOTE",
          "BID"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Why the optimizer don't use all 3 columns without explicit declaration of index?

> Added:

A'm I understanding right, I should to use request like this?

> Reuest example:

```
EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON
SELECT
  BID
FROM 
  Rate
WHERE 
  BASE = 'EUR' 
  AND QUOTE = 'USD' 
  AND `TIME` <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
ORDER BY 
  BASE DESC, QUOTE DESC, TIME DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If I understand it right, the output of Explain vouldn't be better. There are still only 2 columns are used without TIME

> Explain Output

`{
      "query_block": {
        "select_id": 1,
        "cost_info": {
          "query_cost": "10384642.20"
        },
        "ordering_operation": {
          "using_filesort": false,
          "table": {
            "table_name": "Rate",
            "access_type": "ref",
            "possible_keys": [
              "IDX_UK",
              "IDX_TIME"
            ],
            "key": "IDX_UK",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "BASE",
              "QUOTE"
            ],
            "key_length": "22",
            "ref": [
              "const",
              "const"
            ],
            "rows_examined_per_scan": 46734411,
            "rows_produced_per_join": 23367205,
            "filtered": "50.00",
            "index_condition": "((Developer.Rate.BASE <=> 'EUR') and (Developer.Rate.QUOTE <=> 'USD') and (Developer.Rate.TIME <= ((now() - interval 1 month))))",
            "cost_info": {
              "read_cost": "1037760.00",
              "eval_cost": "4673441.10",
              "prefix_cost": "10384642.20",
              "data_read_per_join": "1G"
            },
            "used_columns": [
              "ID",
              "TIME",
              "BASE",
              "QUOTE",
              "BID"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }`

> Added 2:

I made these 4 requests:

— 1 —

```
 <code>FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT
  BID
FROM 
  Rate
WHERE 
  BASE = 'EUR' 
  AND QUOTE = 'USD' 
  AND `TIME` <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
LIMIT 1;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';</code>
```

— 2 —

```
<code>FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT
  BID
FROM 
  Rate FORCE INDEX (IDX_UK)
WHERE 
  BASE = 'EUR' 
  AND QUOTE = 'USD' 
  AND `TIME` <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
LIMIT 1;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
</code>
```

— 3 —

```
<code>FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT
  BID
FROM 
  Rate
WHERE 
  BASE = 'EUR' 
  AND QUOTE = 'USD' 
  AND `TIME` <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
ORDER BY 
  `TIME` DESC 
LIMIT 1;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';</code>
```

— 4 —

```
<code>
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT
  BID
FROM 
  Rate FORCE INDEX (IDX_UK)
WHERE 
  BASE = 'EUR' 
  AND QUOTE = 'USD' 
  AND `TIME` <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
ORDER BY 
  `TIME` DESC 
LIMIT 1;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';</code>
```

The output of session_status is the same in all requests except request 3. In output of request 3: Handler_read_prev = 486474;
In output of all ather requests: Handler_read_prev = 0;

[image: Handler_read_prev]

> Added 3:

I made a copy of the table, removed Id field, promoted UNIQUE key as PRIMARY.

The scheme:

```
CREATE TABLE Developer.Rate2 (
  TIME datetime NOT NULL,
  BASE varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  QUOTE varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  BID double NOT NULL,
  ASK double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (BASE, QUOTE, TIME),
  INDEX IDX_BID_ASK (BID, ASK)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 26
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci
ROW_FORMAT = COMPRESSED;

{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "9673452.20"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": false,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "Rate2",
        "access_type": "range",
        "possible_keys": [
          "PRIMARY"
        ],
        "key": "PRIMARY",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "BASE",
          "QUOTE",
          "TIME"
        ],
        "key_length": "27",
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 48023345,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 16006180,
        "filtered": "100.00",
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "68783.20",
          "eval_cost": "3201236.12",
          "prefix_cost": "9673452.20",
          "data_read_per_join": "732M"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "TIME",
          "BASE",
          "QUOTE",
          "BID"
        ],
        "attached_condition": "((`Developer`.`Rate2`.`BASE` = 'EUR') and (`Developer`.`Rate2`.`QUOTE` = 'USD') and (`Developer`.`Rate2`.`TIME` <= <cache>((now() - interval 1 month))))"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now the request really works and Explain shows all 3 columns are used. This variant works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `ID`, it is of no use.  Promote your `UNIQUE` key to be `PRIMARY`.  Now, magically, the query will be faster, and the Question you posed will become moot.  (You may also need the `DESC` trick that lorraine suggested.)

Here's another technique to compare performance:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

I would be interested to see the output from the `SHOW` for with and without the `DESC` trick.  And with/without the `FORCE INDEX` you alluded to.

Why faster?  Your query was using a secondary index, but it needed `bid`, which was not 'covered' by the index.  To get `bid`, the `PRIMARY KEY` needed to be drilled down in the 'data'.  By changing it so that the PK is used, this extra drill-down is obviated.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tryed to create a copy of table without ID and do what adviced to do. _I would be interested to see the output from the SHOW for with and without the DESC trick. And with/without the FORCE INDEX you alluded to._ I added 4 requests to my post. Read "Added 2:" The output of session_status is the same in all requests except request 3. In output of request 3: Handler_read_prev = 486474; In output of all ather requests: Handler_read_prev = 0;

Comment: Cases 1 and 2 are uninteresting since they have not `ORDER BY`, which (I assume) is mandatory for what you are trying to find.  Cases 3 and 4 puzzle me.  Further head-scratching needed.

Comment: I tried to made a copy of the table, removed Id field, promoted UNIQUE key as PRIMARY. Please read the scheme in "Added 3:" in the post. Now the request really works and Explain shows all 3 columns are used. This variant works.

Comment: Rick, I made index IDX_BID_ASK (BID, ASK) anticipating the request vould be processed with this index only. But it doesn't happen. I awaiting to see the string "using_index = true" but it dosn't happen. Do you know why? As I know, actually every btree index contains PRIMARY Key, thereby index IDX_BID_ASK actually contains (BASE, QUOTE, TIME, BID, ASK). And in this case index completely covers the request. So why do MySQL use PRIMARY Key only?

Comment: @mr_blond - what is the `SELECT` where you don't see "Using index"?  The Primary key is clustered with the data, so if the PK is being used for the query, then it is effectively "using index", but won't say so.

Comment: I asked about case when `"The column information is retrieved from the table using only information in the index tree without having to do an additional seek to read the actual row. This strategy can be used when the query uses only columns that are part of a single index."` [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html) So I make a request and get Explain output without `«Using index»: true` string

Comment: @mr_blond - that is called a "covering index".  `INDEX(bid, ask)` is 'covering' for a `SELECT` that mentions _only_ those two columns plus whatever other columns are in the PK.  However, it is most useful when you say `WHERE bid = ...`; but this seems like an unlikely query.  (Note: `bid` is the first column in the index.)  The order of the columns _in the index_ is important for determining the efficacy of the index.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you describe (ref access instead of range access over more columns) reminds me of [Bug#81341](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81341) and [Bug#87613](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87613).  These bugs were fixed in MySQL 5.7.17 and 5.7.21, respectively.  Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySQL  5.7.20-19. I will update MySQL and write you if the behavior will the same

Comment: Updated to 5.7.21, the behavior is the same.